# Can we trigger an event to the browser few minutes before the session expires in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm new to Laravel and I though about a possible scenario.

Let's say we work on a single page, where we design some project. As we work only at that page, we don't send any requests to the server, which means that we can save our project in X minutes after we have loaded the page, where X are the minutes for session time.

I know that from the frontend side we can perform some timeout functions in order to save the project, but without using the frontend, can we trigger a function at, let's say, 5 minutes before the session expires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a variety of methods to achieve this requirement. The easiest solution is to pass in the session validity time to the frontend javascript. So using that value, you can set a timer by using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) from the javascript to give a notification to the user.

One another way is to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), which is supported by most of the modern web browsers, Websockets allow duplex connections, Meaning you can push notifications to the client from the server, But setting this up requires a bit of knowledge in WebSockets, and probably you need to use some services like [socket.io](https://socket.io/) or [pusher](https://pusher.com/channels). Laravel supports both of these services out of the box and provides us with a library called [Laravel echo](https://laravel.com/docs/broadcasting) to do the frontend scaffolding. But this requires a fair bit of knowledge in laravel events & broadcasting, and WebSockets obviously.

Comment: Thanks, for the ideas! I will look at them in details.

Comment: Cool, let me know how it goes.